# C# What's the "+=" for?

Tags: c#, operators

I don't really get what the function of "+=" is.. Could someone explain it to me? Like what's the different between "=" and "+="

I've got something like this now:
b +=(a[i]);

Thanks!

Comment: `b +=(a[i]);` is the same as `b = b + a[i]`

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx) is quite clear.  I suggest using it as a reference source rather than SO.

Answer (score 5):

b = a assigns a to b
b += a assigns b+a to b

Ex:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
b = a;  //b is now 5
```

vs.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
b += a;  //b is now 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b +=(a[i]);
```

It is a shortcut for this

```
b = b + a[i];
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx

Answer (score 0):

b = a[i] + b

But you can use it for add event

Button.Click += new System.EventHandler(Button_Click);